# controllers sub-folders inside area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have sub folder in controller folder in area

Controller

- api

  - UserController
  - Products

    - product1Controller

I want to access product1 controller when the user requests `http://mysite/api/products/product1/Index`

and the views folder like

- Views

  - api

    - User
    - products

      - product1

my apiAreaRegistration.cs like this

```
public class apiAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "api";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {    
            context.MapRoute(
                "api_default",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Offers", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "TracerAPI.Areas.api.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is against of asp.net mvc convention. It cannot be done without deep recoding of Asp.Net MVC Framework.

Comment: so you say there is no way that i can create subfolder in controller folder inside an area?

Comment: Yes. In ASP.Net MVC you cannot do this.